# Define object's methods before its constructor in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, constructor

Is it possible to deinfe a class' methods earlier than its constructor in Javascript?

Something like:

```
MyObj.prototype.fcn = function () {};
MyObj = function () {};
```

That's because I'd like to separate the instance methods to a different file, but it would be better to load that file earlier than the file with the constructor.

The best solution would be if it would not depend on which file is loaded first.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't paint a house before it's built

Comment: @charlietfl : In JS, I wouldn't be surprised if it were possible :-D

Comment: Create a global dummy object, and inherit its prototype.

Comment: @Teemu : Seems interesting. But Object.prototype is not sufficient?

Comment: @peci1 that would affect all objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

This is the basic implementation of the prototypal inheritance. You can create a constructor and add properties to it in "File 1". Then in "File 2" you can inherit the properties from the early created constructor like this:

```
// File 1
var Dummy = function () { /* A */}; // Dummy needs to be able to refer globally
Dummy.prototype.methodA = function () {alert(this.constructor);};

// File 2
var BConstructor = function () { /* B */};
BConstructor.prototype = new Dummy(); // Include properties of Dummy too
BConstructor.prototype.methodB = function () {alert(this.constructor);}; // Create more properties if needed
BConstructor.prototype.constructor = BConstructor; // Make sure BConstructor will be the constructor of future-created objects

var a = new BConstructor();
a.methodA();
a.methodB();
```

Comment: @peci1 I've improved the code, now it's easier to create new objects in "File 2".

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to alter a prototype of a not-yet-defined object.

Answer (score 0):

Try delaying setting the prototype methods to after the document is ready.